# Go to a specific page if account is not activated in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have user and account model and the association is user has_one account.
For authentication, I'm using devise gem. Whenever a user registered for the first time, an account is also created. But the account will be inactivation state. This will be in active state when the admin gives access to the account. If it is inactivation state then I need the page to redirect to the specific page where it will show Waiting for activation.
I have used the below code

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  redirect activation_path
end
```

But if the user clicks on the other links it should not go to that page, it should be restricted and redirect to the activation path saying that under activation process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could, for example, add a `before_action` for this

```
class ApplicationController
  before_action :check_activation

  private

  def check_activation
    redirect_to activation_path unless current_user.account.active?
  end
end
```

TODO:

- make sure anon users (`current_user` is nil) are handled properly
- do not perform the redirect if current page is the activation page (or it would cause a redirect loop)

Comment: Yes, I did this but when I'm clicking on the sign-out link again it is redirecting to the activation page because it is entering to this action before the session is deleted.

Comment: @Rahul: ah yes, forgot about this special case. Maybe there are others too.

Comment: so now i'm even checking for referrer.path.split("/").include?"sign_out"